# Getting Maven Build to include empty directories

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin

I am trying to get maven to include an empty directory which is just used for output files created by the webapp (which is why it is empty).

I have googled and the maven-resources-plugin seemed to be the best option for this, the documentation states that the property includeEmptyDirs is since 2.3 and I am using 2.4, however this seems to do nothing and so far the only way Ive managed to get the directory to create is by putting a text file into it, I dont really want to do this if Maven should be able to do this for me.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Below is my build section from the pom file:

```
<build>
   <finalName>MyApp</finalName>
   <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>          
            <configuration>
              <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>                           
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
          <configuration>
            <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>           
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Where should the empty directory be located after the war file is being deployed ?

Comment: In the web app section of the war file at the same level as jsp and html files. I tried adding an empty java package to see if that got created but it also didnt appear in the war file.

Comment: How could you write in there from within the application? Does not make sense to me. May be you should take a look at the [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#webResources).

Comment: What do you mean how could I write in there? Its just a directory owned by tomcat, so files can be written there by code running in the web app. This is a legacy app thats been up and running for years and it generates pdf reports etc to this directory and provides users with a link to their unique file. I didnt write it, Im just trying set the project up to work under maven.

Comment: @khmarbaise - Thanks for the help, your answer was correct, including the tag includeEmptyDirectories inside of the maven war plugin was the right way to go instead of using the resources plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the maven-war-plugin which has a configuration item includeEmptyDirectories.